# How to find out the time someone amended information on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows

Someone has logged onto my computer, removed some information of mine and deleted my copy.

I know the time frame within which this was done all that need to know is the particular day on which this was done so I do some back-checks with the people that were using my laptop during that specific time.

Comment: Have people logged into the account they used since? (I am assuming every user has his or her own account and that when the *someone* borrowed your laptop he or she logged in with another account).

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Much of the information that would tell you this, has to be enabled, before Windows will log this information.  The average Joe doesn't need to know when he last logged in normally.

Comment: "some information of mine", "my copy" Can you be more specific? Are you talking about (a) file(s)? "logged onto my computer" Do you mean into your account? Is this in a network or just a stand alone computer? Has the computer been used since that incident? Are you interested in retrieving that file or do you just want to confront the person who did it? You really have to write better questions if you want people to help (note that someone already downvoted your question).

Answer (score 2):

Windows can write an event log entry every time a file is accessed (or deleted). This must be enabled with a local security policy and as a setting on the files to audit. You can read [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399/en-us) to see how to enable that.

Windows can write an event log entry every time a user logs on or off. This must be enabled with a local security policy. You can read [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941595(v=ws.10).aspx) for how to do that.

Both solutions above require you to take an action **before** the problem occurs. In your case I'ld try to look at the "previous version" feature for the filesystem, which also must be enabled, but is by default on Windows 7. Go to the folder where your file once resided, right click "restore previous versions". You can browse the old files when selecting a version and pressing the button "open". If "previous version" is enabled on your hard disc/folder you might have luck and be able to narrow down the time slot in which the file deletion occured.

(I only have a German Windows 7, so the texts given above might not be accurate.)